# To change the fonts in the zen cart template

Tags: fonts, zen-cart

I have started a zen cart custom theme using the default theme. Now I hosted the site in my [Test Link](http://sh1.nettantra.com/u/cmFuaml0/nt/ecommerce/zencart/dvdshop/)

In that site I have used the default theme for creating a custom theme. but I changed the theme as per the requirements. Now problem is that the fonts used in the site not working. I used the font creator site to create font and then put it in my template

The path to the fonts directory

`~Rootdirectory/includes/templates/dvd_shop/fonts/`

and use the font in the css file

`~Rootdirectory/includes/templates/dvd_shop/css/stylesheet.css`

but now I got the forbidden message in my firebug. So I don't know where to use the fonts in the custom template.

Comment: have you got any further with this? I am having the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12056008/fontface-403-forbidden-error#comment16100888_12056008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in comments I had a similar issue and have managed to solve it, you need to edit the .htaccess file in the includes folder as well as set correct permissions - see my question and answer here: [@fontface - 403-forbidden error in zen cart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12056008/fontface-403-forbidden-error/12059850#12059850)